# How would you make a toon glass shader in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, glass

I saw plenty of Eevee toon shaders (and let's be fair, Eevee is just better for toon shading), but how would you go about making a Cycles Toon Glass Shader? I tried making something that I'm linking below, but it just doesn't look as good.

I found a shader test video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u47lZDnfD6g) that uses Cycles (you can tell from the thumbnail). The shader looks awesome.

[image: toon shader on youtube]

How would you recreate the shader from the video, or do you have any solutions for Toon Glass in Cycles yourselves?

[image]

Comment: How do you know it was rendered with Cycles? The thumbnail of the video looks similar to the screenshot. Where is there a hint about Cycles?

Comment: @Blunder it says path tracing done in top left corner and the glass is noise as well. ![image](https://imgur.com/a/7CeyHqJ).

Comment: Ah, thanks! I've overlooked this line

Comment: Break it down into the different elements you would expect and tackle each one separately. For example, the video you provided appears to be made up of the base glass colour (volume?), the surface reflection and the “refraction” moving in the opposite direction. Those three elements could all be produced separately and then combined for the full effect. Perhaps start by defining how you expect it to look and behave and try and achieve each effect separately.